# How can I know if user enters more than 1 character as input? And if he enters more than one character I want to store that in character array

Tags: c

```
scanf("%d%c%d",&num1,&dummy,&num2);
```

Here num1 and num2 are intergers and dummy is an character. 
As character can only hold one digit or alphabet, I want to store the input in character array if user enters more than one character.

Comment: use `scanf("%d%s%d",&num1,&dummy,&num2);` with `dummy` being a `char[]`

Comment: @CIsForCookies why not posting it as answer ?

Comment: If you want to validate the format of the input, `scanf` is probably the wrong choice.   Use `fread` and parse the data.

Comment: hmm, if I am correct, String is represented by character array in C, so maybe you can simply read input and put into char array variable? But I guess there will be problem with whitespaces

Comment: Probably not if I use %[^\n] instead of %s as format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

Using `scanf("%c",&num1,&dummy,&num2);` will only scan 1 character as the format string (i.e. "%...") says only one `char` (`%c`) is expected.

Instead, you should use:

```
  int num1,num2;
  char dummy[100];
  scanf("%d%s%d",&num1,&dummy,&num2);
```

This would scan two numbers to your `num1, num2`, and will scan a string (which can also be a single char) into `dummy`